# Conditional probability new variable

Tags: calculus, probability

Variables $X_1, ... , X_N, N$ are independent
$X_i - \exp(1)$ and $N$ have geometric distribution with parameter  $\frac{1}{2} $ .

We have a new variable $Z= \min(X_1, X_2 , \ldots , X_N)$

I must calculate $ \Bbb P(N=1| Z >1 ) $

...........................................................

I'm doing that

$ \forall i  X_i - exp(1)\to g(x)=e^{-x} \Bbb1_{(0; \infty)}$
and $P(N=k)= (\frac{1}{2} )^k$

$ \Bbb P(N=1| Z >1 ) = \frac{\Bbb P(N=1, Z >1 )}{\Bbb P( Z >1 )}=\frac{\Bbb P (X_1 >1) * P(N=1)}{\Bbb P( Z >1 )} $. 
How calculate $\Bbb P( Z >1 )$
?
Help me . Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\left(Z>1\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(Z>1\mid N=n\right)P\left(N=n\right)$$
Here $P(N=n)=2^{-n}$ and: $$P\left(Z>1\mid N=n\right)=P\left(\min\left\{ X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right\} >1\right)=e^{-n}$$
so that: $$P\left(Z>1\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2e)^{-n}=\frac{1}{2e-1}$$